# How do I execute a Jar file in a new process and close the original Jar?

Tags: java, jar, runtime, execution, terminate

I have 2 jar files.  I want Jar A to open Jar B then have jar A terminate, leaving Jar B running. How would I go about doing this?

EDIT: I meant I want JarA open in one instance of the JVM, then I want JarA to exectue JarB in a new instance of the JVM then JarA uses system.exit(0)

Comment: By *"close the original Jar?"* ITYM close the JVM running that Jar.  But I prefer the 'classpath' strategy of @gd1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start a new JVM you would start external `java` process just like any other OS command, look up the documentation on [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

```
 ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("java", "-classpath", "B.jar", "B.BMain");
 Process p = pb.start();
```

There are lot of caveats to starting external process in Java, you will find lot of material here on SO searching for `Process` and `ProcessBuilder`

---

`jar` files don't run or terminate; that is the `jvm`, started for example by the command `java`. For example when you run the following command:

```
java -classpath A.jar A.Main
```

A new `jvm` is started and it executes the `main` method of the class `A.Main`

Now that method `Main.main()`, *can* call methods of classes in `B.jar`, if it was in classpath. For example if the command was

```
java -classpath A.jar;B.jar pkg.A
```

Then in `A.Main.main` there can be

```
 B.SomeClass.SomeMethod()
```

Where `B` is in `B.jar`

Is this what you mean when you say "open B.jar"? Note that this does not "close" the other "A.jar", whatever that may mean.

Comment: I meant I want JarA open in one instance of the JVM, then I want JarA to exectue JarB in a new instance of the JVM then JarA uses system.exit(0)

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to launch a new JVM instance for running the other Jar, and then terminate? This is not so common.

Alternatively, you could just include Jar B into the classpath and use the classes it provides from within the code in Jar A.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, even after reading below answers, that you still want to invoke "JAR-B"  in a separate JVM process which is not attached to parent process "JAR-A", your best bet perhaps is to use something similar to "cmd /start" (for windows) or using 'sh ... &' (for *nix) (from your java program in JAR-A)

Answer (score 0):

I had a possible and partial answer:

So if you are using Java on Windows, then you can use
`new ProcessBuilder("java", "-classpath", "B.jar", "B.Main").inheritIO().start();`

This will not only start the process, but it will begin it in the same Command Prompt Window. For quitting JAR A, include a `System.exit(0);` in JAR A's main method right after creating process B.

For Linux builds, I'm not really sure, as I'm stuck in the same/similar issue for my program.

[Create a new process in Java, exit the current process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63068015/create-a-new-process-in-java-exit-the-current-process)

EDIT: I did post my answer in the above question of mine. :)