# Create a new process in Java, exit the current process

Tags: java, process, restart

In my code, I want to restart the program. For this i have used the following code in Windows:

```
if(System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows"))
{
    //For Windows Builds use this
    new ProcessBuilder("java", "Launcher").inheritIO().start();
    System.exit(0);
}
```

For Linux Builds I used

```
else
{
    //For Linux/Unix or Mac Builds use this
    new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c" ,"java Launcher").inheritIO().start();
}
```

So now, the implementation for Windows works just fine. It begins a new instance and exits the old.
But the Linux implementation is kinda a bit odd. I added `System.exit(0);` thinking that it will kill the current process right after creating the new one, but it seemed to exit the process itself. I cannot restart the program in anyway in Linux, although it was doable in Windows.

Would appreciate help and feedback!

EDIT: [28-July-2020]

So I did find that the new process is created, but the IO is not inherited to the new session. I tweaked a bit of code and now the program creates the new process, gets IO control and after entering a command, it exits.

```
if(System.getProperty("os.name").contains("Windows"))
{
    //For Windows Builds use this
    new ProcessBuilder("cmd", "/c", "java Launcher").inheritIO().start();
    System.exit(0);
}
else
{
    //For Linux/Unix or Mac Builds use this
    long pid = ProcessHandle.current().pid();
    System.out.println(pid);
    String a=String.valueOf(pid);
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    System.out.println(new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", "-c", "java Launcher").inheritIO().start());
    System.exit(1);
}
```

Without `System.exit(1);` the program continues with the newly created process, but with the old process still running in the background. When I try to kill the old process, both the processes are killed.

Here are the new screenshots, with the code specified above.
https://gofile.io/d/MAYLeJ

EDIT: [29-July-2020]

Been working more on why the code is not working. I did get an exception for the same code, which WSL didnt detect!

[The Error Log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O5Odf.jpg)

Comment: Maybe the child process is linked to the parent process and get killed when the parent is killed?

Comment: So how do i unlink it? 
Is there a solution where i can restart my program afresh?

Comment: No idea, but this where I would look to find a solution.

Comment: I tried to find possible answers but I'm back to square 1. I didnt find a satisfactory answer at all.

Comment: Does your Linux launch run at all (if comment out System.exit)? This issue could be something to do with the bash launch and sharing IO from current process which exits. Try without bash / `inheritIO()`.

Comment: https://gofile.io/d/qy9jWi

This was the result.

Comment: So an update here. I used top commands to see the processes running/

The top command reported that a new java instance was created, but the bash did not inherit the control even after explicitly specifying the `inheritIO()` method in `ProcessBuilder`

Can you please help me further? Thank you.

Edit: Link for the pic https://gofile.io/d/zVo0no

Comment: Can you update you question with full example of the code used? Also it might help to print the `pid()` of new process to confirm which matches your screenshot `ps`.

Comment: I have reflected the changes in the question. Thank you for the suggestion for PID `pid()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I did find the right answer and it might be a bit complex, but I shall try to make it as simple as possible.

In this, we will require 2 separate classes: 1 class to monitor the child process, 1 class which is the main process.

For the sake of simplicity, I shall name the monitoring class as `SessionManager` and the main class as `mainClass`

In the SessionManager class, I've implemented the following code.

```
try
{
    //A loop which will run infinitely to montior and start new processes
    while(true)
    {
        //Create the process and listen to the exit code generated by the child process spawned.
        ProcessBuilder session_monitor=new ProcessBuilder("java", "<classname>");
        Process process_monitor= session_monitor.inheritIO().start();
    
        //wait for the child process to end before proceeding
        process_monitor.waitFor();
                
        switch(process_monitor.exitValue())
        {
            //Implement the logic here
            case 0: //do something
            break;

            case 1: //do something
            break;
        }
    }
}
catch(Exception E)
{
    E.printStackTrace();
}
```

And in the `mainClass` program, we shall have a main method to start the process running.

```
class mainClass
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        //exit the process with a code for the SessionManager's logic to work
        System.exit(0);          //Using a normal exit code here
    }
}
```

This has worked for me, and if you think this implementation can be improved, I'd love to hear it. Thank you for all your support :)